# select distinct name from table A where table B contains a keyword and name from Table A

Tags: sql, recordset

I would like to know how to query a SQL database having two tables that match a keyword in a particular order.

Table A contains a list of names such as

`'Jelly','Jam', and 'Juice'`

Table B contains a list of names separated by colons such as

```
Jelly:Blueberry:3oz
Jam:Stawberry:3oz
Jam:Grape,1oz
```

where the first colon separated name is always contained in Table A.

I want a `distinct recordset` from table A whose name is the first colon separated name in Table B and Table B contains the search keyword contained in a lookup variable.

So, if my search keyword were `Stawberry` for example, I want to obtain a recordset that only contains the name `Jam`

If my keyword were `3oz`, my recordset would contain only `Jelly` and `Jam`

-EDIT-
The database is MS SQL Server.  It does not support substr as far as I can tell.  I don't need or want multiple columns.  Table A is basically a category table or Parents table.  It contains a list of all known product categories.  Table B is a detailed products table that contains more specific inoformation about each of the parent categories where each detail is separated by a colon, therfore ach row in Table B contains a colon separated item of the parent category and the first item is the parent itself (which also exists in the parent table (Table A).  Table B has rows like 'Jam:strawberry:3oz:Smuckers' etc.  I want to get a list of the parents whose details match a keyword of my choosing.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Do you really need table A? something like `select substr(names, XXX) from tableB where names like '%:%' || param` should do the trick (given your database supports substr and like).

Comment: Can you provide some more examples of the desired output?  Do you want things on multiple rows, in multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of down and dirty but should satisfy what you are looking for.  Since the first value in your string list is going to be the value you are looking for the statement just grabs the left side of the string.  Your "search" value will always be either surrounded by a colon or have one to the left so in the search that is why they are in the list of values to look for rather than doing a "like" surrounded with "%" because that could find unwanted values.

```
DECLARE @SEARCH_VAL VARCHAR(255) = 'YOUR VALUE HERE'

SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE NAME = (SELECT LEFT(NAME, CHARINDEX(':', NAME, 0)-1) 
FROM TABLE_B WHERE NAME IN (':'+@SEARCH_VAL+':', ':'+@SEARCH_VAL))
```